# Add block to queue with addOperationWithBlock and use completion block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, concurrency

I have a process with 3 steps. Each one needs to be completed before the other (synchronous, serial, etc.). All of them need to be done in background so as not to block the UI.

I'm trying to rearchitect things a bit to use 2 queues, one for network ops, one for db updates to protect core data. Bouncing back and forth between the queues, i can keep things serial, just firing off a block and then having that call something when it's done.

I'm using addOperationWithBlock to create the operation and enqueue it, but dont see the obvious way to do a completion block (like i do with setCompletionBlock for example). I'm not sure how to start step 2 when that's done. Am i overthinking it and i just call the next method (the starting point for step 2) at the end of the block for step 1? Problem is things inside those blocks may be async like AFNetworking calls.

here's some code and more info. I want to hit the server, grab the data, then on completion perform something else, but link them so it must go from data to verification step serially:

```
self.networkQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
self.networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
self.databaseQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
self.databaseQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

[self.networkQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSString *listURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:GET_LIST,BASE_URL];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:briefListURL];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: request
                                                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                                                                self.list = [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)JSON];                                                                                                    
                                                                                            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                                                                [self listOperationDidFail];
                                                                                            }];

        // define block that will execute when the task is finished
        [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
            // Latest data retrieved. Check if db needs updating
            [self verifyList];
        }];

        [operation start];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier to answer with your code, but you can do things serially, asynchronously using nested calls within the blocks...

```
- (void)doThreeAsynchThingsSeriallyThenInvoke:(void (^)(void))finished {

    [self doTheFirstThingThenInvoke:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self doTheSecondThingWith:result thenInvoke:^(BOOL success) {
                [self doThLastThingThenInvoke:finished];
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

Edit - To further elaborate, let's say doTheFirstThing is about doing a network call then parsing the result:

```
- (void)doTheFirstThingThenInvoke:(void (^)(id, NSError *))finished {

    NSURLRequest *request = // form a request, etc.
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:someQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        id parsed = nil;
        if (!error) {
            parsed = // parse the result contained in NSData *data
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
        // here's the important part: invoke the completion block either way
        // it will get either nil and an error, or a parsed result and nil
        finished(parsed, error);
    }];
}
```

... and let's say that doTheSecondThing is for storing data in the database:

```
- (void)doTheSecondThingWith:(id)parsedData thenInvoke:(void (^)(BOOL))finished {

    // you can do something asynch here, maybe on an operation queue
    // or some other way off the main.  Let's say it's an animation, because
    // that takes a BOOL block and we can demonstrate just passing our
    // block param along

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                     animations:^{ self.someView.alpha = 0.0 }
                     completion:finished];

    // see?  we passed the finished block directly to the animation
    // it will be invoked after the animation is complete
```

In summary, the first thing (network request) happened asynch, off the main, and invoked a block when it was done.  The block invoked the second thing (animation) which passed it's block along to an aysnch operation.  The third thing will start only after the network request and the animation (which both ran off the main) are finished.

Comment: hi dan, thanks so much for response, i really appreciate it. i updated my post with some code. trying to understand the nesting example you pasted and i dont totally understand, sorry. so doTheFirstThingThenInvoke would have the actual code of the first thing and that call knows to invoke the block (second thing) when done? if the first thing contains an async call, how does it not bounce back and start second thing after firing off the async call?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is async process in completion block of block in queue.

This recipe should help:

1. Create instance of NSOperationQueue. Set maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1.
2. Declare all your block processes and their completion blocks. Place there anything you want. At the beginning of each block process, place piece of code that suspends created NSOperationQueue. At the end of each block's completion block, place piece of code that unsuspend the same queue - if you call async process inside your block or his completion block, you need to place/call that unsuspending code at the end of that async process.
3. Add all your blocks into NSOperationQueue.

You could also make job done by nesting each process inside other's process completion block.

Comment: thanks so much for the response! i edited my post with code. and i def was trying to use opqueues and max count. so for the completion blocks, like ive done above, is that right with setCompletionBlock on the operation? problem is when i run, its hitting that completion block before it hits the success or failure block, how is that possible?

Comment: I've edited your code. Code is not tested, but should work well. If you call a different async operation inside your async operation, which is already in operation queue, the queue won't "wait" for all your async operation in that block. Other words, you can only execute synchronous code inside one operation block in queue. That's why I've suggested the queue suspending.

Comment: thanks again! ive tried the setCompletionBlock, but my code is getting to that code before it ever hits the success or failure code, how would this happen?